# How to use java reflection in jython?

Tags: java, python-3.x, jython

I am new to Jython. I want to use Java reflection API in Jython. I read some forums but nothing helps me. I used the below Java code and it is working fine.

```
Class[] paramString = new Class[] {java.lang.String.class}
Class cls = Class.forName("ReadExcel")
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("read", paramString)
Object clone = cls.newInstance()
method.invoke(clone, "test")
```

But i don't know how to use it in Jython. Please provide me if any good tutorials available for Jython.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16774535/1083704) of iterating class methods. [This one](https://bitbucket.org/clach04/jyjdbc/src/ce6e8384f3b9758c9b31251edb769831bc92886e/jyjdbc/__init__.py?at=default#__init__.py-298) shows how to hack (i.e. extend) a classpath at runtime.